# SQL: querying a single-date table with a daily-flag table

Tags: sql, date, flags

I have two tables as per below - one table has a row for each ID, and a date when a certain event happened (or null if the event hasn't happened yet); the other table has a row for every date that a warning flag was marked 'Y' for each ID, if the flag wasn't marked there's no row for that ID and date:

(note UK date format)

```
ID    Event Date
1     04/09/2018
2     null
3     05/09/2018
4     07/09/2018

ID    Date         Warning Flag
1     01/09/2018   Y
1     02/09/2018   Y
1     03/09/2018   Y
2     01/09/2018   Y
2     02/09/2018   Y
2     03/09/2018   Y
3     01/09/2018   Y
3     02/09/2018   Y
3     03/09/2018   Y
4     01/09/2018   Y
4     02/09/2018   Y
4     06/09/2018   Y
```

I want to select any IDs with an event date that has a warning flag marked on the day prior to that event date, along with the date that string of warning flags began. So

```
ID  First Warning Date
1   01/09/2018
4   06/09/2018
```

ID2 doesn't have an event date; ID3 doesn't have a warning flag on the day prior to its event date; and ID4 has two strings of warning flags, but only the most recent string should be counted.

I have zero idea even how to start this, any pointers?

Would you rearrange any of the tables/build a summary table before trying to build a query, or can it all be done in a single query?

[this will eventually be coded by someone else in Oracle or HiveQL but I want to understand the query logic before it gets that far as they will just ask me anyway :) ]

Comment: Is the warning flag always `'Y'`?  Or is your data misleading?  Also, what database are you using?

Comment: It will eventually be in Oracle or HiveQL (BigData platform). And yes the flag is always 'Y' - if the data included all IDs for all dates where the flag was 'Y' the table size would be enormous.

Comment: Apologies, should have been 'if the data included all IDs for all dates where the flag was 'N' the table size would be enormous.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation on groups-and-islands problem.  You can start by dividing the warnings into ranges.

Note that date arithmetic is specific to databases, so the exact syntax varies by database.  But this is the idea:

```
select min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate
from (select df.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from dailyflag df
     ) df
group by date - seqnum * interval '1 day';
```

Next, use this for the `join` and then some date arithmetic gets your result:

```
select e.*,
       (e.event_date - df.mindate + 1) as numdays
from events e join
     (select min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate
      from (select df.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
            from dailyflag df
           ) df
      group by date - seqnum * interval '1 day'
     ) df
     on e.event_date - interval '1 day' between df.mindate and df.maxdate;
```

I must emphasize that this is essentially pseudo-code, because the date functions need to be customized for whatever database you are using.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you - I'll look up groups and islands, and over(partition) is something I never got my head around so I'll research that too. The coder will eventually build the query but I need to meet him halfway in explaining what we need and this will help.